# magento2 show text swatch as dropdown in product listing age

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.3.1

I want to show dropdown attribute on product listing page but Magento is not providing that functionality so I have created attribute as text swatch now I want to show that attribute as a dropdown on the product listing page.

it is possible to create a dropdown of text swatch?
in list.phtml attribute as displaying through this line

```
<?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product) ?>
```

[image]

like this i want to create a dropdown

Answer (score -1):

In order to change the text swatch to Dropdown. You need to do following steps

1. Login to Admin got to `Stores -> Attributes -> Product`
2. Open particular swatch attribute Change `Catalog Input Type for Store` Owner from `Text Swatch` to `Dropdown`. After that add Dropdown options and save attribute.
3. Clean cache

**I hope this will help**

Comment: but that dropdown is not showing in product listing page I want to show that on product listing page

Comment: Look I change the attribute representation from text swatch to dropdown. where ever that attribute show, it will show as the dropdown.

Comment: but magento2 does not show dropdown attribute on lisitng page we have customize it

Comment: @AshishRamchandani you mentioned in your question that you already able to fetch the option in product listing, as you attached the screenshot as well

Comment: @AshishRamchandani As per your question, I didn't mention the way of fetching product option in product listing page. I just mention the way how you convert the `text swatch product option attribute` to  `dropdown product option attribute`.

Comment: i have created the dropdown but now i want save that dropdown value before add to cart please tell me the event name